# How can I add to list object all within same class and file?

Tags: c#, list

My code snippet below :

```
public class Database {
    // fake class 
    public class databaseEntry
    {
        public Notification myNotification { get; set; }
        private string myStatus { get; private set; }
    }

    // fake notifications
    Notification notification1 = new Notification();
    Notification notification2 = new Notification();

    // fake database of type databaseEntry in List data structure
    List<databaseEntry> myDatabase = new List<databaseEntry>();

    // add fake data to fake database
    myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification1, myStatus = "approved"});
    myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification2, myStatus = "pending"});

    }
```

Current problem is CS0103: the name "myDatabase" does not exist in current context for last two lines of code.

Obviously I have instatiated "myDatabase", so I dont see why Visual Studio is saying that "myDatabase" does not exist.

I rougly followed example provided at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: depends where you have this code line `myDatabase.Add(`?

Comment: we need more context. If these lines are all in the same method then it is impossible to have this error. Please explain where you declare the myDatabase variable and where you use it

Comment: could you explain further Rahul? Im not sure what you mean

Comment: that list add call should be inside a method likewise shown in MSDN link. Also, your `myStatus` property is marked as `private set` and thus you call  `myStatus = "pending"}` should throw error.

Comment: Steve, I declare  myDatabase in 3rd segment of code and use it in 4th. All my code is inside one class.

Comment: All right but if myDatabase is declared inside a method (thus is private to that method) you cannot use it in another method. The context I was talking about are the methods inside that class

Comment: Fixed my problem. Add was not inside a method, but just a class. How did you guys know this , and why would it matter?

Comment: @js_55 We know that it wasn't in a method because we didn't see a method in your code. It must be in a method because you can only have statements in methods.

Answer (score 0):

use the ctor
need two to now pop list on every
you have no myStaus and notification has issues
a class to have List of itself is odd

```
public class Database {
// fake class 
public class databaseEntry
{
    public Notification myNotification { get; set; }
    private string myStatus { get; private set; }
}

// fake notifications
Notification notification1 = new Notification();
Notification notification2 = new Notification();

// fake database of type databaseEntry in List data structure
List<databaseEntry> myDatabase = new List<databaseEntry>();

public DataBase() 
{
    // need to do it in the ctor
    // add fake data to fake database
    myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry(true) { myNotification = notification1, myStatus = "approved"});
    myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry(false) { myNotification = notification2, myStatus = "pending"});
}

public DataBase(bool skip) 
{
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add these `databaseEntry` items in the constructor to your `List<T>`. Adding them inside your class this way is not possible in C#. You can create an instance of a type but not call methods on it.

```
public class Database {
    //fake class
    public class databaseEntry
    {
        public Notification myNotification { get; set; }
        private string myStatus { get; private set; }
    }

    //constructor of your DataBase class
    public DataBase(){
        // add fake data to fake database
        myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification1, myStatus = "approved"});
        myDatabase.Add( new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification2, myStatus = "pending"});

    }

    // fake notifications
    Notification notification1 = new Notification();
    Notification notification2 = new Notification();

    // fake database of type databaseEntry in List data structure
    List<databaseEntry> myDatabase = new List<databaseEntry>();

}
```

---

Another way would be a list initializer. There you can avoid the constructor and add the items directly at the `List<T>` definition. This initializer did not work other than calling `Add` but you can use it direct at the field definition.

```
List<databaseEntry> myDatabase = new List<databaseEntry>(){
    new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification1, myStatus = "approved"},
    new databaseEntry() { myNotification = notification2, myStatus = "pending"},
};
```